# How to properly deploy .jar file using Tomcat (Or another solution?) on an EC2 instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

So I have a Spring API which I packaged as a .jar file. I would like to run this perpetually on my EC2 instance. I have downloaded tomcat 8.5 from aws-extras onto my instance and have placed the jar file in the .lib subfolder and started tomcat but I can't query the API.

Am I missing a step or is there a better way to do this without Tomcat?

The API works when run with java, but I would like a solution that has it constantly running on the server.

Comment: The jar may be a spring boot app. Try java -jar path/to/your_file.jar

Comment: It is yeah, I was trying to find a way for it to run in the background. I did this in the end with ```nohup java -jar path/to/jar.jar &```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I found to do this is with the following command.
`nohup java -jar path/to/jar.jar &`
This ensures the jar will run as a background process.